# Mass update of records

Tags: salesforce

I have a custom object called Sales Target 
I have 2 lookup fields for contact(Contact__c) and owner(OwnerId) in that object.
I have about 100 records where I need to change the Owner field to Contact field.

Any clues.

Answer (score 0):

Contact records cannot be Owners of other records. Owners must be Users or Queues. You will not be able to make this change as written.

If your Contacts represent community users, you'll need to pull out those users' Ids instead.

Once you have User Ids in hand, you can make the change using any one of the many available data loaders for Salesforce, such as the Data Loader or the Data Import Wizard. You'd perform an Update operation in the data loader and would need to supply the Id of the record to update and the desired OwnerId value on each row.